# How would I return data in a query function

Tags: javascript

Okay I'm a bit new to JS and I have a query within a function here:

```
let queryFunction = testNames.forEach(function(name, index){
    query("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", name)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(name);
        //  let start = data['Time Series (60min)']['2020-04-30 12:30:00']['1. open']
        //  let end = data['Time Series (60min)']['2020-04-30 12:30:00']['4. close']
        //  let score = (((end - start)/start)*100)
        //  console.log(score);
         //Need last 7 fields
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        });
        return data;
    });
```

How would I properly return the data from the query so that queryFunction equals the data from the query?
Whenever I call the function it comes out Undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `query` here? Seems like a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: it's just a bunch of parameters for a third party API

Comment: ```
const query = (function_name, symbol, interval = "60min") => fetch(
    base + "/query?" + new URLSearchParams({ "function": function_name, symbol, interval, apikey })
)
```

Comment: Ok, so it is just a wrapper function for your fetch calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `forEach` you can use map to return an array of promises and then use `Promise.all` to resolve those

```js
const resultPromises = testNames.map(function(name){
    return query("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", name)
    .then(response => response.json())
}

Promise.all(resultPromises).then(results=>console.log(results))
```

Comment: if it returns a bunch of fields like this:
'2020-04-09 14:30:00': [Object] 
How would you be able to see inside that object?

Answer (score 0):

Since query is `async in nature`. You have use either `callback` or `async-await` or `promise-then` to collect data.

```
const scoreMap = (data) => {
  let start = data["Time Series (60min)"]["2020-04-30 12:30:00"]["1. open"];
  let end = data["Time Series (60min)"]["2020-04-30 12:30:00"]["4. close"];
  let score = ((end - start) / start) * 100;
  return score;
};
const queryMap = (name) =>
  query("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", name)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(scoreMap);
const getAllSeries = async (names) => {
  let scores = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
    const name = names[index];
    const data = await queryMap(name);
    scores.push(data);
  }
  return scores;
};
const getAllParallel = async (names) => {
  const promises = names.map(queryMap);
  return await Promise.all(promises);
};

//How to use:

getAllParallel(testNames).then((names) => console.log(names));
getAllSeries(testNames).then((names) => console.log(names));
```

**Sample:**

```js
const getTodos = (id) => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+ id).then((response) => response.json())
const getAllSeries = async (names) => {
  let scores = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < names.length; index++) {
    const name = names[index];
    const data = await getTodos(name);
    scores.push(data);
  }
  return scores;
};
const getAllParallel = async (names) => {
  const promises = names.map(getTodos);
  return await Promise.all(promises);
};

//How to use:

getAllParallel([1,2,3]).then((names) => console.log(names));
getAllSeries([1,2,3]).then((names) => console.log(names));
```